# How do I convert a normal visual basic collection class object to MSVBVM60 Collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vba, exception

I'm facing a problem while converting a normal visual basic collection to MSVBVM60 collection.

Here is the snippet of the code I have used.

```
MSVBVM60.Collection x = new MSVBVM60.Collection();

Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection y = new  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection();

.
.
//y = func(); I get 'y' from this function.

x =(MSVBVM60.Collection)y;
```

Now, this step of mine fails with an exception "Microsoft C++ exception: EEMessageException at memory location 0x04B2CBDC."

So, can someone please help me with this??

Comment: I'm creating a com dll that uses this x as a parameter in another VB application.

Comment: You cannot create a VB6 Collection in C# code, only VB6 code can create them.  Your C# code will throw an exception on the first line in your snippet.  You really need to improve your debugger setup so you can diagnose managed exceptions.  Use the VS debugger instead.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, select "Start external program" and select VB6.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a very good solution to this specific problem.

Here is the link. Go for the workaround

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323737